# python preserving indentation by writing to file

Tags: python

I have a python code which will group the same words present in paranthesis and will take the remaining text and combine.But the problem is its not preserving the indentation after writing.

MY CODE:

```
import re
import collections
class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []

with open('text.txt','r+') as f:
    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')
    current_group = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = group_pattern.match(line)
        if m:    # this is a group definition line
            group_name, group_members = m.groups()
            groups[group_name].members += filter(lambda x: x not in groups[group_name].members , group_members.split(','))
            current_group = group_name
        else:
            if (current_group is not None) and (len(line) > 0):
                groups[current_group].text.append(line)
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()

    for group_name, group in groups.items():
        f.write("%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(group.members)))
        f.write( '\n'.join(group.text) + '\n')
```

text.txt

```
  Car(skoda,audi,benz,bmw)
    The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
 ......

  Car(Rangerover,audi,Hummer)
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

Expected output:

```
  Car(skoda,audi,benz,bmw,Rangerover,Hummer)
    The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
 ......
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

But getting as:

```
Car(skoda,audi,benz,bmw,Rangerover,Hummer)The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
 ......
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

Comment: You _explicitly_ remove whitespaces when you write `line = line.strip()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the leading and trailing whitespace with this line:

```
line = line.strip()
```

Comment: when i remove this line it entirely destroys by producing unwanted spaces to my text.please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problems were in how your were  formatting the lines before you wrote them.

```
import re
import collections
class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []

with open('text.txt','r+') as f:
    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')
    current_group = None
    for line in f:
        m = group_pattern.match(line)
        if m:    # this is a group definition line
            group_name, group_members = m.groups()
            groups[group_name].members += filter(lambda x: x not in groups[group_name].members , group_members.split(','))
            current_group = group_name
        else:
            if (current_group is not None) and (len(line) > 0):
                groups[current_group].text.append(line)

    with open("text.txt","w") as f:
        for group_name, group in groups.items():
            f.write("%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(group.members)))
            f.write("\n")
            f.write( ''.join(group.text))
            f.write("\n")
```

Comment: i m sorry,its not providing expected output.My idea is the text following the group name should also be added for same group names.but also by preserving the indentation!

Comment: Its not writing correctly,it misses lots of text and it not grouping the text!Hoping for your reply!